# Problems installing latest version of R in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, r

I've been trying to install R 4.1 on ubuntu and each time I get the same error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.2-1.2004.0) but 3.6.3-2 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.1.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.2-1.2004.0) but 3.6.3-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I looked it up and it appears to be a common problem and I tried all the solutions suggested - Uninstalled and reinstalled R, deleted and recreated a new /etc/apt/sources.list file, restored default repositories, made sure focal-cran40 is on the sources.list, updated and upgraded everything. But i'm still having the same problem. This is my code

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install r-base
```

Here is the output of apt-cache policy

```
sudo apt-cache policy r-base r-base-dev r-base-core r-recommended
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
r-base-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
r-base-core:
  Installed: 3.6.3-2
  Candidate: 3.6.3-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.3-2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
r-recommended:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.2-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on fresh 20.04 LTS VM. Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base r-base-dev r-base-core r-recommended` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1373827/edit).

Comment: I added the apt-cache policy. Any solutions to fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) You have incorrect output of r-base-core (correct will include universe as orogin for https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r-base-core ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

This may because of the source.lists file. I have met the same problem. As the official install method, you have to run the command as follows:

```
add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
```

if you have add a various of repository, this may be the reason why you met this problem. Maybe you should edit your `/etc/apt/source.lists` and remove the other repository and just remain the only official repository.

Comment: Sorry your answer is not clear. What does this mean? if you have add a various of repository ,

Comment: Before I run into official installation method, I have run some other command such as `add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran35/"` (dd-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/" is the right command for my OS) . When I run the command `apt install r-base` It show the same error as yours.After I delete the wrong repository in source.lists and run the `apt update ``apt install r-base`. I found it can success install R

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. It looks like the version of the default libraries are not compatible, specially **r-base-core** is only available in version 3.6.3-2 (check using `apt-cache show r-base-core`)

Given that some libraries were not available in version 4.x, I decided to install version 3.6 using the following code and it worked:

```
apt install r-recommended=3.6.3-2 r-base=3.6.3-2 r-base-dev=3.6.3-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible hat you are trying to install R on Ubuntu for ARM64?
I was having the same problem when trying to install R on ubuntu on an arm64 machine.
I did install R from source.